Lightning cable bundle testing
I have two wires going to a solenoid. Power and ground. The wires are in in shielded bundle. When we apply a induced lighting voltage let's say waveform 5A, will both wires will be impacted equally? I want to connect a flyback diode between these two wires and not sure weather lighting can impact this diode if the two wires having zero potential.

Show a schematic, edit the question and draw one with the tool.
